# File-systems on both the device and the partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-drive

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on in the following situation. It seems messed up.

This is the pertinent part of the output of `lsblk`:

```
sdc           Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS amd64  28.8G 2021-02-09-19-06-26-00
└─sdc1        KStone-32-ntfs              28.8G 07F22BEC06D2F0E3
```

The output above corresponds to a thumb drive (KingStone USB stick ~30GB) that apparently has two file-systems on it:

One filesystem on the device level:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/usb/
mount: /media/usb: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
$ df -T /media/usb/
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc       iso9660   2809792 2809792         0 100% /media/usb
```

… and another filesystem on the partition level:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb/
$ df -T /media/usb/
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      fuseblk  30217720 66908  30150812   1% /media/usb
```

The device-level filesystem is an ISO image of Ubuntu that I had created using a specialized program (such as `unetbootin`) in order to install Ubuntu on a machine. The partition-level filesystem was created normally with `fdisk` and `mkfs.ntfs`.

Is something messed up? If so, how to format the thumb drive properly and bring about a sane situation? (I've no data I need to keep on it).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "messed up".  ISOs are often made that way so they can be used with either optical media or flash drives.  When you're done using the live environment or installer, you can create a new partition table if you want.